# javascript in my webview have been disabled

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i had uncommented the line below to keep my java script classes but it does not work and my javascript does not work.

```
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
public *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the javascript in your webview

```
WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```